# In JavaScript, is there a start scroll event for the iPhone browser?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari

I would like to detect when a user *starts* to scroll a webpage in the iPhone web browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onscroll` event as usual and delete it when the user scrolled for the first time.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    alert("I saw that!");
    window.onscroll = null;
}
```

Comment: is this the correct way to delete an event? shouldn't you assign to undefined or null?

Comment: @stivlo: It works, but I don't know about "correct". The default value seems to be `null`, so I changed it to that.

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the issue mentioned in the question because the event is nullified and it only runs once and not for any subsequent scrolling event.